# Produce 3 way Venn with a larger circle representing the rest of the sample size

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I would like to create a 3 way venn diagram with and a larger circle behind it representing the sample size.

Example of a two way venn diagram with a larger circle indicating the sample size:

```
library("VennDiagram")

grid.newpage()
venn_AB <- draw.triple.venn(area1=count_A, area2=count_B, area3=count_sample, n12 = count_AB, 
                                  n23 =count_B, n13 =count_A, n123=count_AB,
                                  category=c("A",
                                             "B",
                                             "Sample Size"),
                                  col="Purple",fill=c("Red","Blue", "Yellow"), lty = "dashed", print.mode = c('raw', 'percent'))
```

Venn Diagram (AB)

[image]

However, when I apply the same technique for a three way venn diagram:

```
grid.newpage()
venn_ABC = draw.quad.venn(area1=count_A, area2=count_B, area3=count_C, 
                               area4 =count_sample, n12=count_AB, n23=count_BC, n13=count_AC, 
                               n14= count_A,n24=count_B, n34=count_C, n123=count_ABC, 
                               n124=count_AB, n234=count_BC, n134=count_AC, n1234=count_ABC, 
                               category=c("A",
                                          "B",
                                          "C",
                                          "Sample size"),
                               col="Purple",fill=c("Red","Blue","Orange","Yellow"),lty="dashed",print.mode = c('raw', 'percent'))
```

Venn Diagram (ABC)

[image]

I get a four-way leaf diagram.

Expected Venn Diagram (ABC)

[image]

Is there any way to produce the expected result within R?

Answer (score 0):

Any generalized Venn diagram generator should do that, even if the result is not very pleasing aesthetically. The trick is to add a set that is the union of the other sets. For instance, you might try to do that in `eulerr`. With my own `nVennR` package (https://github.com/vqf/nVennR), you could do something like this:

```
> library(nVennR)
> setall <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'r', 's', 't')
> seta <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
> setb <- c(1, 7, 8, 9)
> setc <- c(2, 5, 9, 10)
> myV <- plotVenn(list(A=seta, B=setb, C=setc, U=setall), setColors=c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'grey'), opacity=0.4)
```

And, as result,

[image: Venn diagram with line for universe]

The grey set is the universe, with the lower circle representing elements that are not in sets a, b or c (in the example, 'r', 's' and 't').